# NextJS: How to navigate from url to a custom path?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a menu component use  to navigate internally in my website like :

`<Link href="/containers/grades/List" as="/grades">`

I use "as" to keep clean my URL 
but the problem is the navigated page cannot be refreshed; if I refresh the page I get 404 error.

I know that "as" is used for showing a custom address in URL but I need a way to get to the component from URL
in this case, I want to navigate from `"/grades"` to `"/containers/grades/List"`

is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `<Link href="/containers/grades/List" as="/grades">` you have client side route and for server side just add this below code to your next.config.js;

```
 experimental: {
      async rewrites() {
        return [
          { source: '/grades', destination: '/containers/grades/List' }
          ];
       }
    }
```

this will wire them up.

Comment: In Next v.13 you dont need add this code inside the experimental, only add async inside modules.export.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic page you would do use the `useRouter` for dynamic routing between pages.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Dynamic = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { dynamic } = router.query;

  return (
    <div>
      My dynamic page slug: {dynamic}
    </div>
  )
}
```

export default Dynamic
And you can link to it like this:

```
<Link href="/[dynamic]" as="/dynamic-page-slug">
  <a>Link to my Dynamic Page</a>
</Link>
```

You can also make your custom routes by adding next.config.js file:

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      // 307 temporary redirect
      {
        source: "/",
        destination: "/under-construction",
        permanent: false,
      },
      // 308 permanent redirect
      {
        source: "/posts",
        destination: "/blog",
        permanent: true // permanent redirect
      },
      // With parameter and custom status code
      {
        source: "/photos/:id",
        destination: "/photo/:id",
        statusCode: 303 // see other
      }
    ];
  }
};
```